# Is it possible to take feed from two back cameras simultaneously in android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I want to take two camera feeds separately so that I can use it for stereo vision but I am not able to find any resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the back cameras are arranged too close to produce a meaningful stereo pair. The exception are devices originally designed for stereo shoots, like HTC Evo 3D. The latter came with dedicated SDK that allows third-party developed to take advantage of its stereo camera.

Technically, independent access to individual lenses of the back camera array is supported by camera2 API since Android Pie, see https://source.android.com/devices/camera/multi-camera. But this support comes on manufacturer to manufacturer, device to device basis. Some of them don't provide access to physical camera devices. Some don't because their hardware is not compatible with these APIs. Others, because their software is not up-to-date.